# Given two sorted lists (or arrays) and a number k, create an algorithm to fetch the least k numbers of the two lists

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Need to find the first 3 smallest number in given two sorted array. I supposed that two array should merge into one first and sort it in order to fetch the first 3 smallest number. Can anyone help me with the merge and sort part or provide some advice, any help will appreciate.

This is where i reached now, I only can get the smallest number ( not first 3, just one).

```
public class MergeandSort {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] set1 = {1,2,6,9,18};
    int[] set2 = {2,3,7,10,21,30};

    int smallest = set1[0];
    int smallests = set2[0];

    for(int i=0; i < set1.length; i++){
        if(set1[i] < smallest)
            smallest = set1[i];
    }
    for(int k=0; k < set2.length; k++){
        if(set2[k] < smallests)
            smallests = set2[k];
    }

    System.out.println("Smallest Number in Set 1 is : " + smallest);
    System.out.println("Smallest Number in Set 2 is : " + smallests);


}
```

}

Comment: This is much easier as you think now. For example the smallest element can only be the first element of set1 or the first element of set2. What are the possibilites for the second and third element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MergeandSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] set1 = {1,2,6,9,18};
        int[] set2 = {2,3,7,10,21,30};
        int[] sorted = new int[k];

        int smallest = set1[0];
        int smallests = set2[0];

        int i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
        while(i < set1.length && j < set2.length && c < k){
            if (set1[i] < set2[j])
                sorted[c++] = arr1[i++];
            else
                sorted[c++] = arr2[j++];

        while (i < set1.length && c < k)
            sorted[c++] = arr1[i++];
        while (j < set2.length && c < k)
            sorted[c++] = arr2[j++];

        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

where **k** is the count of sorted numbers you want

Answer (score 4):

The arrays are already sorted, so you don't have to iterate over the entire arrays to find the 3 smallest numbers.

- You just have to start iterating over both arrays at the same time (i.e. in the same loop).
- In each iteration you compare the current two elements of the two arrays (starting at the 2 elements at the 0 index) and take the smaller of them
- Then you advance the index of the array from which you took the smallest number.
- Once you reach 3 elements (after 3 iterations), you break out of the loop.

Here's some pseudo code to get you started:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int c = 0;
int[] lowest3 = new int[3];
while (true) {
    find the smaller of set1[i] and set2[j] and put it in lowest3[c]
    if set1[i] is smaller, increment i
    otherwise increment j
    increment c
    if (c==3) // you are done
        break;
}
the lowest3 array now contains the 3 lowest numbers of both arrays
```

Of course you can swap 3 with any k. You just have to make sure that i is always smaller than `set1.length` and j is always smaller than `set2.length`.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are already sorted, just implement the merging technique of merge sort with the limitation in while condition that it should run only k times (in this case 3), but dont forget to check that size of sets are less than k or not!

```
        int k = 0,i = 0,j = 0;

        while (k<3 && k<set1.length && k<set2.length )
        {
            if (set1[i] <= set2[j])  
            {
                final_set[k] = set1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                final_set[k] = set2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

         while (k<3 && k<set1.length) {
           final_set[k]=set1[i];
           k++;
           i++;
       }   

      while (k<3 && k<set2.length) {
           final_set[k]=set1[j];
           k++;
           j++;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

That would not work as:

Array1 = {1,3,5}

Array2 = {2,3,4}

Correct solution: {1,2,3}

Output of your solution: {1,3,4}